# Array.push is not working with promisified function but callback is not retaining the message

Tags: node.js

Note - Message variable is not retaining data after calling promisified functions. Callback is giving null array.

Code -

```
'use strict';
const Promise = require('bluebird');
let _connectResolve, _connectReject, onConnected = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        _connectResolve = resolve;
        _connectReject = reject;
    }),
    redis = require("redis"),
    redisClient = redis.createClient({
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 6379
    });
Promise.promisifyAll(redis.RedisClient.prototype);

redisClient.on('connect', _connectResolve);
const results = Promise.all([
    'it/0I0g2I3D312s192u0U3k/10es.zip',
    'items/25210B0c0Q1L3u0X462g/10ges.zip',
    'items/2x0n440V1A1n3x1y0f1K/Fs.zip',
    'items/2l023931u0w1S2a3j/es.zip',
    'items/2O2x212i3t0B2h/es.zip',
]);

var message = [];
var a = Promise.promisify(function(callback) {
      results.map(function(result) {
        redisClient.getAsync(result).then(function(reply) {
            if (reply == null) {
                message.push({
                    "key": result,
                    "bucket_name": 'dsdds'
                });
            }
            //console.log(message);
        });
        callback(null, message);
    });
});

onConnected.then(() => {
    Promise.resolve(a()).then(function(message) {
        console.log(message);
    });
});
```

Output - message is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few things wrong with how you've coded this.  Asynchronous operations run on their own schedule and finish some indeterminate time in the future.  As such, you can't do something like use a `.map()` loop with asynchronous operations in it and then expect the results to be ready right after the `.map()` loop.  Instead, you have to use tools to keep track of when all the async operations in the `.map()` loop have completed and look at the result only when that tool tells you all the operations are done.

In addition, there are some very weird uses of `Promise.promisify()` which makes it look like you think promisifying a plain function will somehow magically manage the async operations inside it.  It will not.  You can only use `Promise.promisify()` on an async function that has a specific calling convention.

Fortunately, since you have the Bluebird promise library, you can use its tools to help you to do something like this:

```
function a() {
    let message = [];
    return Promise.map(results, function(result) {
        return redisClient.getAsync(result).then(function(reply) {
            if (reply == null) {
                message.push({
                    "key": result,
                    "bucket_name": 'dsdds'
                });
            }
        });
    }).then(function() {
        // make the message array be the resolved value of the returned promise
        return message;
    });
});

onConnected.then(() => {
    a().then(function(message) {
        console.log(message);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , I was looking for PRomise.map kind of stuff only. Appreciated your help.